# Inconsistent internet connection device (eth0 eth1 eth2)

Tags: networking, ethernet, ifconfig

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, and to my knowledge there is only 1 networking card on my machine (Dell laptop) --- I can't imagine why there would be more than 1.

Sometimes my internet connection runs over device `eth1`, at other times `eth2`.  Possibly also `eth0` at times.  I don't care much which device name is used, but I **do** care that it always be the same.

(Since I always connect wirelessly, I expected the connection to run over a `wlanX` device based on my experience with Ubuntu 10.04, but, like I said, the name doesn't matter as long as it's consistent).

Running `ifconfig` returned:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5c:26:0a:16:e4:31  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:22 Memory:f6fe0000-f7000000 

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:56:b2:16:3e  
          inet addr:192.168.1.78  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:56ff:feb2:163e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9970442 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:2735811
          TX packets:7466676 errors:501 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1991253521 (1.9 GB)  TX bytes:594939490 (594.9 MB)
          Interrupt:17 Base address:0xc000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:2634 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2634 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:287326 (287.3 KB)  TX bytes:287326 (287.3 KB)
```

The contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` were:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

**After running `ifconfig` and viewing the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`, I edited `/etc/network/interfaces` and entered `# /etc/init.d/networking restart`**

Now, the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` are:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

And running `ifconfig` now returns (where `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` and `YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY` are not the actual addresses):

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5c:26:0a:16:e4:31  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:22 Memory:f6fe0000-f7000000 

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:56:b2:16:3e  
          inet addr:192.168.1.78  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:56ff:feb2:163e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10329105 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:2751349
          TX packets:7712653 errors:609 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2531013388 (2.5 GB)  TX bytes:614377694 (614.3 MB)
          Interrupt:17 Base address:0xc000 

eth0:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5c:26:0a:16:e4:31  
          inet addr:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  Bcast:YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:22 Memory:f6fe0000-f7000000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:2751 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2751 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:303844 (303.8 KB)  TX bytes:303844 (303.8 KB)
```

**So, my question is:** do the changes I made to `/etc/network/interfaces` have the effect of forcing the internet connection always to be run over device `eth0`, or at least always to be aliased by device `eth0`?  If not, then after undoing my changes to `/etc/network/interfaces`, what can I do so that I can always refer to the internet connection device as `eth0`?

**[Added below in response to request.]**

The contents of `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` are:

```
# This file was automatically generated by the /lib/udev/write_net_rules
# program, run by the persistent-net-generator.rules rules file.
#
# You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single
# line, and change only the value of the NAME= key.

# PCI device 0x8086:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0 (e1000e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="5c:26:0a:16:e4:31", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x14e4:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:0c:00.0/ssb0:0 (b43-pci-bridge)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:25:56:b2:16:3e", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

# PCI device 0x14e4:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:0c:00.0 (wl)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:25:56:b2:16:3e", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"

# PCI device 0x14e4:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:0c:00.0 (wl)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:25:56:b2:16:3e", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth2"
```

Comment: can you post the contents of `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`

Comment: @max Done.  Any ideas?

Comment: id would try removing all those lines and rebooting for some reason the same device is listed 3 times as eth1 wlan0 eth2

Comment: @max OK.  As long as I backup the file, there shouldn't be any disasters, right?  Worst case scenario, internet connectivity would be down until I restore from the backed up file.  Right?

Comment: you dont even need the file at all it would be auto regenerated if you delete it

Answer (score 2):

Device names are auto-assigned for each different piece of hardware.  See the "HWaddr" entries?  Each of those is a different MAC address.  The system stores and remembers each and every hardware you have, so that each of them gets a different label and can be identified as different devices.

I don't believe you can set it up so that everything can be "eth0", if you use multiple hardware.  But, you can change the labels on each interface (do so CAREFULLY).

Comment: The problem is that I run conky to display network transfer rates.  Conky requires the device name.  Since it changes on my machine, sometimes conky displays transfer rates for the wrong device.

Comment: The device names shouldn't be changing, except maybe in a LiveUSB environment.

Comment: That's what I would have thought.  However, they sometimes do change.  At least, they did change before I edited `/etc/network/interfaces` as shown in my original question.  Any idea why them might be, or have been, changing?

Comment: It could be a bug, or it could be an issue with LInux and the card in question, I'm not an expert in diagnosing the situation.